# Get core dump from CGI process with lighttpd

Tags: linux, cgi, lighttpd

Using lighttpd (version 1.4.35) on Linux:  How can I get a core dump from a CGI program that exits with `SIGABORT` (or `SIGSEGV` for that matter) instead of lighttpd trapping the signal?

Are there lighttpd configuration options to prevent `lighttpd` or `mod_cgi` from trapping the signals?

I can modify & recompile the CGI program to reset the signal handler of interest, but I would rather do this with modifying the code in question.

EDIT:  Here's the message I see from lighttpd:

`(mod_cgi.c.1312) cleaning up CGI: process died with signal 6 
 mod_cgi.c.1050: aborted`

Comment: The signal is sent to the CGI process, not the `lighttpd`. Your CGI program could call `syslog`, `setrlimit`, `sigaction` ....

Comment: See edit for log message.  Is `mod_cgi` getting that from the exit code of the `cgi` program then?  Haven't looked at `mod_cgi.c` yet.... was hoping I wouldn't have to.

Comment: `mod_cgi.c`  is probably calling `waitpid` ... Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: Yes, it is.  But it turns out the problem was for a static file that was being misinterpreted as a cgi program due to ".conf" file issues :P.

Comment: a clarification on what the conf issue is could of been helpful to others